Confused between induced emfs

We know when flux of B changes an EMF is induced in loop
And also when a rod moves in mag field Potential difference between its ends is also produced.
So is this ques while writing Potential equation
Why we take only Bdv in calculation and not 2Bdv
(Bdv is EMF due to Flux change which is similar to motional emf between rods Bdv)
And also if they are same thing then how?
Motional emf is due to motion of electrons from one end to other while faraday's law is a law.

Because they're the same thing. Literally two different ways of calculating (or two different ways of thinking about) the same thing,

But why are they not two different things that have to be added? The only way to know that is to go back to the underlying Maxwell equations. They overrule all "rules" that have been devised for specific phenomena. Also "EMF" does not have a universally accepted definition so its use can make questions ambiguous (although that is not the problem here, this question is clear. It is about double counting).

@march how are they same? motional is due to motion of e- from one end to other while the faraday is even applicable when there is no motion
